# How can I do login with OAuth2 (Identity Server 4) using flutter web?

Tags: web, flutter, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

I have been trying to do Oauth2 login of Identity Server 4 using flutter. I have successfully implemented the login on iPad using: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_web_auth library but as this library says it also supports web but seems like it is not working on the flutter web app.

how can I make the web app work with Oauth2 or is there any other way to make the OAuth2 login work with flutter web?